# Как удалить цифру ноль

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Помогите новичку,  в call-центре при звонке открывается страница, и с помощью API номер прописывается в этот тэг

```
input type="text" name = "number" maxlength = "20" size = "20" style = "font-size:14px; onclick="fun()" value="?=$_GET['call_numb']?
```

проблема в том что не как не магу удалить первую цифру ноль . 
 0506314752
написал этот скрипт , но это не то

```
if(a>1) {
  a = a.substr(1);
}
  alert('<?=$_GET['call_numb']?> : ' + a);
}
```

это функция при нажатии,но не удаляет, надо при звонке как апи вставит номер.

Comment: плюсик добавьте `... value="<?= +$_GET['call_numb']?>`, если подразумевается что у вас там только цифры в строке.

Comment: Тема закрыта.
Спасибо ThisMan очень помог, со стороны сразу видно :)